# How can I allow my Vagrant instance to connect to a python server on the host?

Tags: port-forwarding, vagrant

So I'm running a Laravel dev site using Homestead, and but I have a python server that the Laravel instance needs to talk to, and I'd like to keep that python server on my host machine. How can I allow my Homestead instance to access that server? I've tried port forwarding though Virtual box's settings, but after reading some of the virtual box docs I get the impression that the NAT network device is a one way street. Am I right in that assumption? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.